# Fantasy story about a boy who finds a dragon egg

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm looking to identify a book I read in the very early 2000s, it was about a boy who found a dragon egg (I think it was set in England) there was a merlin-type character who helped him and a side character called "Milo"? I barely remember the plot but I think the main character's dad worked at a museum or something.

Comment: [Jeremy Thatcher, Dragon Hatcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175023/help-me-identify-this-novel-about-a-boy-with-a-dragon-egg) possibly? Though his father is a vet and there is no character called Milo.

Comment: Maybe "Pillage" by Obert Skye? The boy protagonist found a dragon egg and had a friend called Milo - didn't live with his father though.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez: Sounds like it's good enough for an answer to me. Partial matches are valid matches too.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez that book is from 2008 so it's a bit later than suggested in the question, but I'd say it's still worth posting as an answer. The Merlin-type character could be Beck's uncle Aeon.

Answer (score 4):

I hesitate a little to suggest this, as although it matches on some points, it also misses on a few. Could the book be "[Pillage](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2775759-pillage)" by Obert Skye?

**Points in favour:**

The boy protagonist, Beck, finds some stone eggs and hatches them into dragons.

He has two friends, one of whom is called Milo.

**Points against:**

The story is set in America rather than England (though I think the family is originally from Scotland).

Beck lives with his uncle, rather than his father (his mother and father died I think, leaving him to be brought up by his uncle). But in fact:

> it is revealed in a plot-twist near the end, that the man he thought
>  was his uncle *was* in fact his father.

As @JohnRennie points out, with a publication date of 2008 it's a bit too late to have been read "in the very early 2000s".