# Book about a boy who moves to Europe, climbs a wall with one of his friends (who turns out to be a troll), and finds dragon eggs

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, dragons

There was a book I read in middle school about a boy who moves to Europe and moves in with his elders. While there, he finds a stone building in the back; after climbing the wall with one of his friends, he finds dragon eggs. Also, the boy's friend turns out to be a troll who wanted to get the dragon eggs for himself the whole time.

Comment: Similar to this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229773/fantasy-story-about-a-boy-who-finds-a-dragon-egg/229780#229780

Answer (score 9):

Might this be *[Pillage](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2775759-pillage)* (2008) by Obert Skye?

[image]

According to this synopsis from Goodreads, the main character, Beck, is sent to live with his uncle in a remote manor house:

> Upon his mother's death, fifteen-year-old Beck Phillips is sent to live with an eccentric uncle he had never met in a remote manor house, where he learns that his family suffers from a curse that allows him to make plants grow on command and dragon eggs hatch.

[This exerpt from a review at From The Bookshelf of T.B.](http://ftbotbblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/pillage-by-obert-skye.html) mentions that Beck finds the dragon eggs when he climbs over a wall in the back garden of the manor:

> It turns out that Beck’s suspicions are true, something strange is going on. He finds out what when he finally climbs over an abandoned conservatory wall, in the back garden of the manor. He uses his newfound talent, of instantly growing plants, to climb over the solid and very tall wall! What he finds inside is amazing! Dragons! Well, not quite. He does find dragon eggs though, and mistakenly hatches them.

And according to [this Amazon customer review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3U2BA8C2L1W7Z/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B002UQHYJW), a character named Milo:

> reveals he's some sort of troll/magician thing

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.

Comment: Can a new member who only has a rep of 1 mark something as an answer?  Just curious.

Comment: A new user with a reputation of 1 can mark answers to their own questions as accepted, yes.

Comment: good to know.  thanks